# How to declare array of strings with string index?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

In my code i declared like this :

```
public string[] s ;
```

and i need to use this string like this :

```
s["Matthew"]="Has a dog";
s["John"]="Has a car";
```

when i use s["Matthew"] an error appears and it says "Cannot implicitly convert 'string' to 'int'" . 
How can I make a string array to have string index ?
if i write this in php it works :

```
array() a;
a["Mathew"]="Is a boy";
```

I need it to work also in asp.net !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public Dictionary<string, string> s;
```

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I would suggest it too.

Comment: @StefanP. If it works then mark that answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

In C#, you cannot access an array element using, as array index, a string.
For this reason you have that cast error, because the index of an array is, by definition of an array, an integer.

Why don't you use a data structure like a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();

dict.Add("John","I am John");

//print the value stored in dictionary using the string key
Console.WriteLine(dict["John"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array works on indexes and indexes are in numbers but you are passing string that's why you are getting error, @Christian suggest you to use `Dictionary`

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
            {"key1", "value1"},
            {"key2", "value2"},
            {"key3", "value3"}
    };

    // retrieve values:
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
    {
        string key = kvp.Key;
        string val = kvp.Value;
        // do something
    }
```